# google app script properties service getProperties() returns value as undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have a key value map with JSON in it

```
 var prop = {
    0 : [{"start":0, "end":10}, {"start":15, "end" : 30}],
    1 : [{"start":3, "end":11}],
    2 : [{"start":6, "end":9},{"start":9,"end" :17},{"start":32,"end":39}],
    4 : [],
    5 : [{"start":19,"end":27}]
 };
```

I wanted to save this object in `PropertiesService` `userProperties`, so i first stringified the values (because `PropertiesService` only allow string values) and then saved it.

```
for(var i in prop){
    prop[i] = JSON.stringify(prop[i]);
}
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
userProperties.setProperties(prop, true);
```

Later, when I retrieve property using `Properties.getProperties()` method, it returned the property object.

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var pro = userProperties.getProperties();
```

The problem is `Logger.log(pro)` shows me the `prop` object but when I try to access property values using `pro[index]` as stated in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getProperties()) it returns `undefined`.

When I try to access value using `userProperties.getProperty(i)` it returns me the value.

My question is why I cannot access the properties this way :

```
for(var i in pro){
    Logger.log(pro[i]);   // returns undefined
}
```

but this code below works

```
for(var i in pro){
    Logger.log(userProperties.getProperty(i));  //successfully returns value
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer, the problem is with keys, `PropertiesService` only allow keys and values both to be of `String` type.

```
var prop = {
    "p0" : [{"start":0, "end":10}, {"start":15, "end" : 30}],
    "p1" : [{"start":3, "end":11}],
    "p2" : [{"start":6, "end":9},{"start":9,"end" :17},{"start":32,"end":39}],
    "p4" : [],
    "p5" : [{"start":19,"end":27}]
};
```

and now when i accessed the values using keys, it worked

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var pro = userProperties.getProperties();
for(var i in pro){
    Logger.log(pro[i]);   // returns value successfully
}
```

so keys and values both should be of string type